# ClearCase delay in showing latest config spec

Tags: clearcase, config-spec

Are you aware of any issues with delays in changes to view configuration specifications being reflected in ClearCase explorer etc?

Added following line in a text file and included in the config spec.

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/LATEST
```

In ClearCacse explorer view showed elements in main/LATEST.

Later changed the text file to

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/branch_name/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST
```

saved it and closed.

Refreshed the view and view was pointing to main/LATEST even after stop and starting the view.

confused with the result, side tracked to another task and after 15 mins when I refreshed I saw latest from branch.

Any reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your branch might now always originate from `main`.

Try rather the following config spec:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT 
element * .../branch_name/LATEST 
element * /main/LATEST
```

Comment: Yes, This type of branch is always under main. one more users today informed that he is also faced similar problem. Nothing in log(both vob and view server) Any reason why such delay. Config_spec is just three lines.

Comment: yes, it worked. Thanks a lot for that. any reason for the slowness ? This issue is not frequent happened only twice today.

Comment: @maestromani Are you using that config spec in dynamic or snapshot views? In which type of view do you see that slowness?

Comment: It is a dynamic view and this particular type of branch is always under main. This particular vob have not more than 50 branch.

Comment: @maestromani then no reason comes immediately to mind. I have experienced slowness with ClearCase for a variety of reason, but generally, it responded well (with Vobs having way more than 50 branches).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. Will continue to monitor and come back if I see any issue.

Comment: I have just spotted something.

As stated earlier my view has an 'include' line in it which I am using. If I edit the 'included' file the ClearCase Explorer window still sees the same view details as before the edit no matter what I put into the config spec of the included file.

Comment: However 
As soon as I go to ClearCase Explorer, go to the view propoerties and make an edit to the actual views config spec (even simply adding & then deleting a space character), upon applying the new config spec (eventhough it is the same as the old one) the selected elements displayerd by ClearCase Explorer change to the elements of the 'included' file config spec.

Comment: Vob&View Server --> 7.1.0.2, Client version is 7.1.0.2.

Comment: @maestromani do you include you config spec as described in https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_config_include_files.htm? There was some issue with nested config spec (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000002909093)

Comment: Config spec got only one line, include command for the test.txt file. test.txt file got only element * CHECKEDOUT 
element * /main/branch_name/LATEST 
element * /main/LATEST

Comment: Another question came up my mind now is, refresh in dynamic view check config spec change ? in that case refresh should see the change in include file.

Comment: @maestromani usually, a simply refresh (F5) is enough (or a `cleartool ls`  in command line) for a dynamic view to pick up a config spec change.

Comment: Weird, Not sure why refresh is not bring in the change. Tried in couple of machine and found the same issue.

Comment: Whilst it is good we have appear to have identified part of my problem it does create a larged issue.
I am concerned that Integrator could change the include file but developers continue to use the old (original) version.

Comment: @maestromani I understand? That is why UCM was invented: better communication of common config spec through streams.

Comment: WE have UCM project too but not his one. Sure this will not get moved to UCM. Will have a tough day ahead convincing developer/integrator/PM about this problem.

Comment: Even cleartool ls command line is not working. explicitly open config spec in explorer and edit brings the change.

Comment: @maestromani what about a `cleartool setcs -current`? That should flush and refresh.

Comment: That works like charm, convening developer an extra task(open command prompt and type this) going to be hell. Need to find the automated process. Any how, thanks a lot for the help. It would be nice if IBM find solution. Believe that will not happen.

Comment: @maestromani the developer would have a wrapper for `cleartool` (like a `ct.bat` in his/her `%PATH%`) which would first do the `setcs -current` (if a `cleartool pwv` mentions that the current location is a dynamic view), and then execute the actual `cleartool` command.

Comment: Not this team. Nice to have some thing done like that.

Comment: @maestromani I understand. I am just trying to propose some workaround, and that script isn't hard to write.

Comment: I agree and appreciate your help. Thanks a ton.